# zip file is empty on download PHP

Tags: php

With one of my components in Joomla I am generating a zip file which is readable (when downloading it by FTP) and I can see the contents of it when opening it. Now when pushing it to the browser the file becomes invalid.

My code:

```
    if(file_exists($download)){

        ## http headers for zip downloads
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($download));
        ob_end_flush();
        @readfile($download);
        exit();

    }else{

        exit('File does not exsists.');

    }
```

The var $download does exsists and when downloading it by FTP it is working. After pushing with the above code the zip file can't be opened anymore with IE and Chrome on Windows and Mac's

Best Regards,
Robert

Comment: Does your call to `ob_end_flush()` turn off the output buffer, so should be after the `readfile` call?

Comment: `ob_end_flush()` should be the last thing that happens

Comment: No this is not working at all. So another thinkg should fix the issue..